# Dynamically creating a 2D array in Groovy

Tags: arrays, dynamic, groovy, 2d

I have already gone through all the questions on stackoverflow regarding Groovy 2D arrays and the answers do not seem to suffice. I am also fairly new to groovy hence, I'd sincerely appreciate your input in this regard.

I am trying to create a 2D array in the following way.

```
def extractedArray = []
// fullArray is a 2D array of size[11987][4]

def x = 0
for (x; x<fullArray.length; x++){
    if (x==0){

        extractedArray[] = []

        extractedArray[0][0]=fullArray[0][0]
        extractedArray[0][1]=fullArray[0][2]
    }
    else{

        for(def y=0; y<extractedArray.length; y++){
            //other functions
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems to give me the following error.

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method putAt() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method putAt() on null object
    at computeMPR.main(computeMPR.groovy:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def extractedArray = []
```

this is not array but List initialization

so you can change code:

```
//extractedArray[0][0]=fullArray[0][0]
//extractedArray[0][1]=fullArray[0][2]
extractedArray << [fullArray[0][0], fullArray[0][2]]
```

or if you prefer arrays you can do something like:

```
Object[] extractedArray = [fullArray.size()]

extractedArray[0] = [
                        fullArray[0][0],
                        fullArray[0][2]
                    ] as Object[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this is the problem. With `Object[] extractedArray = [fullArray.size()]`, we're creating the `extractedArray` with the same size as the `fullArray` right? But, in my case, we don't know the size of the `extractedArray`. I simply want to define the array without specifying a size. Then as we push the values to the array, it dynamically increases in size.

Comment: Since we initially don't know how many elements we'll be storing in the array, the array needs to dynamically grow as the elements are inserted. I know how to do this with the other scripting languages like JS, but not exactly sure about groovy. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can't change the size of an array once created. You either have to allocate it bigger than you think you'll need or accept the overhead of having to reallocate it needs to grow in size.

Comment: But this is possible with Javascript right? We simple declare an array and then as we `array.push('x')` elements to it, the array size increases as well. Isn't the same possible with groovy?

Comment: Groovy is based on Java. In java there are no way to create array with dynamic size. Collections are developed to solve this problem. List is much more powerful structure then regular array. And if you need array on the end you can simply transform list to array: list.toArray(new Object[list.size()])

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll try doing so